# Why I can not get model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

There are two models:

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{ 
    public function verifyUser()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\VerifyUser');
    }
}

class VerifyUser extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

I retrieve specific user:

```php
$verifyUser = VerifyUser::where('token', $token)->first();

if ($verifyUser) {
    // dd($verifyUser); // not empty object
    dd($verifyUser->user); // null
}
```

Why I get `user` relation as null?

Comment: is your column name in the verify_users table called `user_id`? and can you confirm that there is an id there in your database?

Comment: VerifyUser has column `user_id`, Users has `id`

Comment: Then use just this: `return $this->belongsTo('App\User');` in your `user` function.

Comment: The same result

Comment: Because your user model doesn't extend model.

Comment: Then in your database for that record `user_id` is `null` most probably.

Comment: @CHARITRASHRESTHA it doesn't have to. It extends Authenticatable.

Comment: `VerifyUser` is returning the user object - isn't this correct when it dumps the `$verifyUser`?  IE if you try `$verifyUser->id` won't that work?

Comment: turn on db listen and dump all the queries fired on page load. That will give you an idea if correct queries are being fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
```

by

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id');
```

or

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
```